# java variable in loop does not count

Tags: java, loops

I have a problem for the following code.
Basically the  `i` in `String foreCon` does not increment, (stays at `0`).
so therefore the `return String` does not show according to the weather forecast.

```
private int i = 0;
public String conditionList2() {
  while (i < WeatherAPI.weatherForecastList.size()) {
    String foreCon = WeatherAPI.weatherForecastList.get(i).forecastCon;
    if (foreCon.equals("Sunny")) 
      return "\uf00d";
    else if(foreCon.equals("Rain")) 
      return "\uf01a"
    else if(foreCon.equals("Cloudy")) 
      return "\uf013";
    i++;
  }
  return "";
}
```

Here is the Cheatsheet used. http://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/cheatsheet/
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give an example of a weatherForecastList and what the expected and actual result is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only incrementing the variable if you don't return immediately from the loop - if the forecast is `Sunny`, `Rain` or `Cloudy`, you hit a return statement and don't increment `i`.

You can just move `i++` to the bit of the loop *straight after* you assign a value to `foreCon`:

```
String foreCon = WeatherAPI.weatherForecastList.get(i).forecastCon;
i++;
if (foreCon.equals("Sunny")) 
...
```

I have to say that it feels like a bit of an odd design anyway - I would separate "iterating through the words" from "transforming words into symbols", personally. (It's also odd that you'll return `""` just once, right at the end of the list. If you implemented an `Iterable<String>` instead, that would be much cleaner.)

Comment: how do you implement with `Iterable<String>` as in this example? Do I do `Iterable<String> foreCon` and `for(String s : foreCon)`?

Comment: @user2875021: You'd need to redesign the code quite a bit, basically - which is beyond the scope of the question, and we'd need to see a lot more context in order to help you properly. But it's something to think about - if you want help with it (after trying yourself) please ask a new question with all the relevant context.

Comment: also for the above example, `i` only increments until `1`. I found this out because it shows `Partly Cloudy` all the way from Fri till Mon in my GUI. whereas according to yahoo weather api, it should be                          `Thu Mostly Clear`
`Fri Partly Cloudy`
`Sat Mostly Sunny`
`Sun Partly Cloudy`
`Mon PM Showers`

Comment: @user2875021: That only proves there's a bug *somewhere* in your code - it doesn't prove that it's still there. It sounds like now would be a good time for you to start using a debugger. (Note that the method we're looking at *never* returns "Partly Cloudy" - it only ever returns one of the Unicode symbols.)

Comment: as in it returns the Unicode symbol for "Partly Cloudy" (because the condition list is too long, I cut the example to just 3.) What I have done is just `weatherForeCon1 = new JLabel(conditionList2())`

Comment: @user2875021: Well I suggest you use a debugger then, or add some logging. You're now talking about code you haven't shown us. Why not try just this code in a simple console app, which just prints out the results as it calls `conditionList2()` until it returns an empty string? (Note that Stack Overflow is *not* an interactive debugging session. We've answered this question; please do not use comments to try to get us to work out what's wrong with the calling code too.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72369/discussion-between-user2875021-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
String foreCon = WeatherAPI.weatherForecastList.get(i).forecastCon;
```

to

```
String foreCon = WeatherAPI.weatherForecastList.get(i++).forecastCon;
```

and remove

```
i++;
```

from later in the code.

Comment: Duplicate answer. Adds no value.